# Quando "pra" será formalizado?

Tags: preposições, história, contrações

Na minha opinião, "pra" ser usado em contratos e leis é apenas uma questão de tempo. Presidentes, governadores, advogados, âncoras de jornais e propagandas falam "pra"; "pra", na lingoagem falada formal, já é aceita, então, eu acho que é apenas uma questão de tempo.

Eu acho que funcionará da seguinte maneira:

> *para* = *pra*
>
> *para a(s)* = *prà(s)* = *pra a(s)*
>
> *para o(s)* = *pro(s)* = *prò(s)* = *pra o(s)*

Porém, tenho dúvida sobre "pró(s)".

Também acho que haverá outras contrações:

> proutro
>
> pralguém
>
> proutrem
>
> pralgo
>
> pralhures
>
> pralgures
>
> praquelotro
>
> praquele
>
> pralgum
>
> etc.

Há fundamento na minha hipótese? E quando "pra" será formal em contratos e leis?

Comment: Espero que NUNCA. É usado na linguagem falada, mas não na escrita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pra, pro, prà, prò

As contrações *pra* + *a* e *pra* + *o* (e respetivos plurais) já existem, mas são grafadas simplesmente *pra* e *pro.* As grafias que tu sugeres, *prà* e *prò*, eram na verdade as grafias oficiais **em Portugal antes do acordo ortográfico de 1990** (mas não no Brasil):

> Ele vai prà China [= para a China]
>
> Ele vai prò Brasil [= para o Brasil]
>
> Ele vai pra Portugal [= para Portugal]

Isto estava explicitamente previsto no [acordo ortográfico de 1945](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1945) (artigo 24), adotado em Portugal mas não no Brasil. Mas o [acordo ortográfico de 1990](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990) (Base XII) prevê o uso do acento grave apenas nas contrações envolvendo a preposição *a* (*à, àquele, àqueloutro, àquilo*, etc.), e o entendimento dos dicionários é que agora *pra* + *a* = *pra* e *pra* + *o* = *pro* tanto no Brasil como em Portugal. Vê [dúvida linguística no FLiP (Priberam)](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1558). De modo que qualquer dicionário atualmente te diz que *pra* é o mesmo que *para* e também a contração de *para* com *a*. Vê [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/pra), [Porto Editora](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/pra), [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/pra), [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/pro/).

Agora, quando é que estas formas serão adotadas em documentos formais, eu nem sei prever, nem levo a sério quem afirme saber. Não sei sequer se alguma vez serão adotadas.

### As outra contrações com *pra*

Quanto às outras contrações que tu sugeres, ouso prever que não serão adotadas. Eis porquê.

Com algumas exceções, as formas que tu sugeres correspondem à pronúncia normal: por exemplo, *pra algum* é naturalmente pronunciado como *pralgum*. Isto não é simplesmente pronúncia descontraída: é a pronúncia normal, apropriada tanto para conversas entre amigos como para discursos solenes (bem, num discurso solene será mais provavelmente *paralgum*). Mas esta contração é um fenómeno fonético muito comum quando duas vogais átonas se encontram. Exemplos:

> Rosa azul              →     rosazul
> Rosa inigualável   →     rosinigualável
> Rosa oculta          →     rosoculta
> Rosa universal      →     rosuniversal

Ora não me parece que faça mais sentido escrever *pralgum* do que *rosazul, cravindiano, leitazedo*  ou, com apóstrofos para facilitar, *el’insult’inimig’armad’e apanh’um balázio*. Mas não creio que alguém queira escrever assim (mas já se escreveu poesia medieval assim, com apóstrofos).

Uma vantagem de não representarmos graficamente estas contrações da fala, é podermos escrever a mesma palavra sempre da mesma maneira. Caso contrário teríamos de escrever (vou usar apóstrofos para facilitar) *ros’ universal* mas, pelo menos no meu sotaque, *rosa única* (o *-a* não se funde com vogal tónica) e *rosa branca*. Pela mesma razão teria de ser *pra algo* e *pra outro* mesmo que fosse *pralgum, praquele*, etc.

Isto de escrever a mesma palavra sempre da mesma maneira reflete a maneira como o nosso cérebro funciona. Diz o psicolinguista Steven Pinker em *O instinto da linguagem*, que acusticamente as nossas frases são um som contínuo (como *elinsultinimigarmado*), mas nós mentalmente ouvimos palavras individuais; ouvimos *rosa* quer o *-a* final seja pronunciado (*rosa branca, rosa única*) quer não seja (*ros’ indiana*). Só prestando deliberadamente atenção é que notamos as elisões de vogais.

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo fundamento na sua hipótese. Vamos por partes.

A linguagem oral não é exatamente formal apenas porque o emissor exerce uma área que, na maior parte do tempo, exige formalidade, tais como advocacia, jornalismo e entre outras. Baseado nisso, é possível afirmar que você está enganado quando diz:

> Presidentes, governadores, advogados, âncoras de jornais e propagandas falam "pra"; "pra", na lingoagem falada formal, já é aceita, então, eu acho que é apenas uma questão de tempo.

Quanto ao uso. Se essas contrações fossem aceitas pela norma culta, algumas não seriam como você disse. Observe:

> para = pra;
> para a/para as = pra/pras;
> para o/para os = pro/pros;

Como você pode notar, eu corrigi as duas últimas frases. A razão disso é que, em primeiro lugar, **para** não exige um artigo, na maioria das vezes. Quando exige (ex.: para a praia), o correto seria simplesmente utilizar "à", já que o artigo **a** já está contraído em "pra". Portanto, é totalmente incorreta a adição do acento grave em "prà", "pràs", "pròs" e "prò". Em segundo lugar, não há necessidade de adicionar um artigo após a contração "pra" ou "pro", pois a contração já contrai a preposição e o artigo.

Em relação a outras contrações, não é questão de "acho que haverá". A maioria das contrações que você citou já existem e são utilizadas, principalmente no meu estado (Ceará). Todas, com exceção de "pralgo", "pralhures", "pralgures" e "praquelotro", que acredito que não existem, são utilizadas com extrema constância, já que é parte do nosso dialeto. Então, suponho que a real questão seja se estas contrações seriam também aceitas pela norma culta e esta pergunta eu respondo abaixo.

Em equidade a "pra" e "pro", acredito que estas contrações não serão aderidas na norma culta. Não é porque falamos algo com constância que está certo. Falamos desse modo porque é mais confortável, mas isso não altera o que está determinado pelas normas.

Por fim, "E quando "pra" será formal em contratos e leis?". Não tenho como saber e afirmar se isso sequer vai acontecer. Esta pergunta não deveria estar sendo feita nessa comunidade, pois trabalhamos com fatos, não com suposições ou opiniões pessoais.

Comment: Concordo que a minha pergunta não envolve fatos e acho que deveria ser removida. Mas eu não entendi a lógica de """'para' exige um objeto direto. Portanto, é totalmente incorreta a adição do acento grave em "prà", "pràs", "pròs" e "prò".""".

Comment: "Em equidade a "pra" e "pro", acredito que estas contrações não serão aderidas na norma culta. Não é porque falamos algo com constância que está certo.", por que "pra" estaria errado? Por que a Norma Culta não aceitaria?

Comment: As contrações "pralguém" e "pralgum", por exemplo, não existem em dicionários e existem na língua falada; eu estava falando da Norma Culta aceitá-las.

Comment: "A linguagem oral não é exatamente formal apenas porque o emissor exerce uma área que, na maior parte do tempo, exige formalidade, tais como advocacia, jornalismo e entre outras", por que "pra" não seria formal na linguagem oral? Já vi muitos deputados, senadores, ministros, âncoras e jornalistas falando "pra' em situações formais.

Comment: N.B.: em pt-PT, diz-se "vou pra casa" mas "vou prá praia" e "vou pró cinema"; pra e prá são claramente distintas, para nós.

Comment: Devo ter escrito incorretamente. Correção: "**para** não exige um artigo, na maioria das vezes. Quando exige (ex.: para a praia), o correto seria simplesmente utilizar "à", já que o artigo **a** já está contraído em "pra".". Isso facilita o entendimento?

Comment: Nada está incorreto, apenas seu uso está indevido. "Pra" é uma contração e, portanto, é informal. Se é informal, não é aceita pela norma culta. Como "pralgum" e "pralguém", por exemplo, são menos utilizadas que "pra", na minha opinião, não há como aceitar essas palavras se o famoso "pra" não for aceito.

Comment: Eu entendi e confirmo isso aqui: "Então, suponho que a real questão seja se estas contrações seriam também aceitas pela norma culta e esta pergunta eu respondo abaixo.". Basta ler o parágrafo abaixo.

Comment: Do mesmo jeito que não é formal na escrita, não é formal na fala. Independente de ser utilizada de modo oral, a contração não deixa de ser informal. No entanto, costumamos utilizar a linguagem oral para nos comunicarmos e, portanto, o objetivo é simplesmente fazer com que o receptor entenda a mensagem. Além disso, como eu já disse, não é porque estas pessoas utilizaram "pra" enquanto falavam que está correto perante as normas.

Comment: @Chanp, qual é a diferença entre "da" e "pra"? Já que "da" = "de" + "a".

Comment: A diferença é que "da" é aceita pelas normas gramaticais. Já "pra", não.